# How can I condense several regex to a one-liner?

Tags: regular-expression, perl, rename

I'm having trouble condensing several regex down to an efficient one-liner. I have file names which are named like this: `Something (0482) - a123b456 - Something [00xcf bxc v32 Something]`. I'd like the results to be `something-a123b456-Something` or `something_-_a123b456_-_Something`

Here are the regex I'm trying to condense:

```
's/(^.*)/\L\1/'   # makes the whole string lowercase
's/\(.*?\)|_//gs' # removes everything between parentheses
's/\[.*?\]|_//gs' # removes everything between square brackets
's/ /_/g'         # substitutes whitespaces with underscores
```

I've tried to chain the commands together, both by hand and by using [this site](https://regex101.com/), but regex is *not* my forte. I'd really appreciate if someone could tell me *how* one chains several commands together, so that I can do it myself the next time.

I am using `prename` (Perl), by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally Perl expressions are chained together with `;` so `s/.../foo/;s/.../bar/;...` for a `rename` style chaining that operates on the implicit `$_` variable. I'm not sure where you got `prename` from so I'll use [my own version](https://github.com/thrig/scripts/blob/master/filesys/rename) of `rename` here. Probably it is pretty similar to yours. The `-p` flag is to preview, or to prevent damage to the filesystem.

```
$ touch 'Something (0482) - a123b456 - Something [00xcf bxc v32 Something].demo'
$ rename -p 's/(^.*)/\L\1/;s/\(.*?\)|_//gs;s/\[.*?\]|_//gs;s/ /_/g' *.demo
rename Something (0482) - a123b456 - Something [00xcf bxc v32 Something].demo something__-_a123b456_-_something_.demo
```

However this can probably be improved; there is no reason to use regular expressions for everything here.

```
$ rename -p '$_=lc; s/\(.*?\)|_//gs;s/\[.*?\]|_//gs; tr/ /_/' *.demo
rename Something (0482) - a123b456 - Something [00xcf bxc v32 Something].demo something__-_a123b456_-_something_.demo
```

So instead we use `$_=lc` to lowercase everything in `$_`, and replace the `s/ /_/` with a `tr`. Or maybe instead runs of white space should be replaced with a single underscore? If so, `s/\s+/_/g`. The `()` and `[]` can probably also be improved on, though that gets more complicated to properly match on such balanced expressions.

On additional study `s/\(.*?\)|_//gs` does not make much sense; there are better ways to kill off `_` characters without that (repeated!) alternation in the `()` and `[]` killing expressions, so:

```
$ rename -p '$_=lc; tr/_//; s/\(.*?\)//gs;s/\[.*?\]//gs; tr/ /_/' *.demo
rename Something (0482) - a123b456 - Something [00xcf bxc v32 Something].demo something__-_a123b456_-_something_.demo
```

The `.*?` could probably be made more efficient by using something like `s/\([^)]*\)//gs` to match only-that-which-is-not-the-closing-character but you probably want readability more than efficiency here. But if you are using regular expressions in one-liners you've already blown your readability budget.

```
$ rename -p '$_=lc; tr/_//; s/\([^)]*\)//g; s/\[[^\]]*\]//g; tr/ /_/' *.demo
rename Something (0482) - a123b456 - Something [00xcf bxc v32 Something].demo something__-_a123b456_-_something_.demo
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you for the excellent write up/explanation. You're right about the readability budget, it was more to learn how to chain up expressions.